# How can I pass data read from a JSON file to the rest of my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new in the scripting and web world and have been trying to work through an issue I've been having. I am reading data from a local JSON file, and have been able to use jQuery.getJSON and jQuery.parseJSON successfully, but I am trying to use the data outside of the getJSON callback function and am having issues. I think it comes down to me not fully understanding the correct way to do this, and that's where I'm looking for your help. Here's my code:

```
var names = new Array();

$.getJSON('ferries.json', function(data) {
  var jsondata = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

  var length = jsondata.nodes.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    names[i] = String(jsondata.nodes[i].name);
  }
});

console.log('Names: ' + names[0]);
```

The final line returns undefined. If I were to write that line right after the for loop, it would return the desired value. Here's how the JSON file is structured:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {
      "name":"John"
    },

    ...

    {
      "name":"Joe"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Edit: One last thing, it seems that the final line (console.log(...)) executes before the $.getJSON bit, which confuses me as well.

Comment: To get names array try this
    names.push(jsondata.nodes[i].name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` runs asynchronously. The function that you pass to it is a "callback", which means that it gets called when `getJSON` comes back from doing its thing.

If you want to do something with the JSON data that you get back, you must wait for the callback to execute.

Also, on a side note, `$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data))` is redundant. The `data` object is already a perfectly usable object with your data in it, but you're turning that object back into a JSON string and then immediately back into an object. Just use `data` as is. For more information, check out the [jQuery API docs for `getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: Thanks for the side note - that makes a lot of sense when you explain it like that. As for waiting for the callback to execute, how can I achieve that in code?

Comment: You're already waiting on `getJSON` to execute the callback to set the  values in the `names` array. Whatever else you need to do, do it within the callback or call another function for the callback to do it. For more complex scenarios, read up on jQuery's Deferred object. The doc page for `getJSON` mentions it.